# Hostgator primary domain to route to subfolder

Tags: subdomain

I have a primary domain xyz.com and now I added a subdomain, abc.com and it is being properly redirected to the subfolder in the 'www' folder abc.com, but where as my primary domain , xyz.com I want to redirect it to the subfolder in the 'www' is not happening what and where I have to change the settings?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ask Hostgator support.

   - They ought to know how their webhosting service works a lot better than any of us.
2. `abc.com` is not a subdomain.

   - Subdomains are delimited by the `.` character.  `efg.abc.com` would be a subdomain.
3. When asking a question here (and in general), it's helpful to imagine that we might not know everything about your environment.

   - To wit..., well, everything about "redirecting" and your "`www` folder."